# view android calendar in titanium

Tags: android, calendar, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to use "Titanium.Android.Calendar" API to view the device calendar (the native one), I've seen the examples in the website but it doesn't help ..

How can I display The device calendar when the user click a button

I tried this code

---

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    className: "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity",
    packageName: "com.android.calendar"
});

Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

---

but an exception appear that

ActivityNotFoundWxception: unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.launchActivity}; have you declare this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

any help in that area will be appreciated ..Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Android.createIntent-method.html) the function `Ti.Android.createIntent()` takes no arguments. You can modify an intent after it is created but not at creation point.

In your case I would try [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Android.Calendar-module) however.

Comment: however the docs clearly show an argument passed in for the example code...? :-/

Comment: in the example they pass an arguments, I tried to use the Calendar API and the example provided, but it shows me the name of the calendar, what I'm looking for is to display the native calendar with its native interface.